# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am calling `java servlet` for logout from my page setting all the values to null and reset the http session as follows:

```
public class logout extends HttpServlet
{
    public void service(HttpServletRequest rq,HttpServletResponse rs)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        try{
            HttpSession ss=rq.getSession(false);
            if(ss.getAttribute("uid")==null || ss.getAttribute("usr")==null || ss.getAttribute("acc")==null)
            {
                rs.sendRedirect("/");
            }

            rs.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
            rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            rs.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
            rs.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);    
            HttpSession session = rq.getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("uid",null);
            session.setAttribute("usr",null);
            session.setAttribute("acc",null);
            session.invalidate();
            rs.sendRedirect("/");
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Catch
        }


    }
}
```

If I click the logout button then it get logout fine. Suppose if I am not logout for some time suppose 30 minutes then press logout button I am getting a blank page instead of redirecting to home page. 
In stacktrace i got the erroe as following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
    logout.service(logout.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I know that it is going to catch because session will expire automatically. How can I handle this? I need to redirect to home page even if it the session expires automatically. What should I do?

Comment: please print stack trace of error here.

Answer (score -1):

If the container's session is expired, then this line

```
HttpSession ss=rq.getSession(false);
```

will return `null`.

---

You are not checking for `not null` before using `ss` variable, which might be throwing exception at runtime.

And also, you need not have one more variable for holding session, You can reuse `ss`.

```
     if(ss != null){
            if(ss.getAttribute("uid")==null || ss.getAttribute("usr")==null || ss.getAttribute("acc")==null)
                        {
                           // rs.sendRedirect("/");
                        }else{        
                        rs.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
                        rs.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                        rs.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
                        rs.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);    

                        ss.setAttribute("uid",null);
                        ss.setAttribute("usr",null);
                        ss.setAttribute("acc",null);
                        ss.invalidate();
                      //  rs.sendRedirect("/");
    }
        }
rs.sendRedirect("/");
```

Comment: ok. So you are saying that I need to check ss == null before going to try???Can you post as an answer then it will be helpful!!

Comment: Getting error page Error mentioned above. I have updated question!!

Comment: Remove or comment the rs.sendRedirect("/") from if block.

Comment: If I do so, then how it will redirect to home page???

Comment: See the updated again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80926/discussion-between-faheem-farhan-and-santhucool).

Comment: It will never make me logout even if my session expires!!

Comment: Solved it. Thank 4 ur help!!

Answer (score -1):

Added some changes in my catch(){} block as following, now works fine.

```
catch(Exception exp)
        {
            RequestDispatcher dd = rq.getRequestDispatcher("/");
            dd.forward(rq, rs);
        }
```